# strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given

Tags: php, strpos

**I'd like the $description to be a string of words pulled from the Description column. Then I want to check if the string has the $searchterm (one word defined prior to this block of code).**

```
//3. (a)for each, (b) if search term is in the description column, put line into sorted table.
// a. number of rows in spreadsheet
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM csv"); 
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($results);

// b. check rows and put into sorted table
    $i=1;
do
  {
  $i++;
  $description = mysql_query("SELECT Description FROM csv");

  if (strpos($description,$searchterm) !== false) {
          echo $description . "<br><br>";
      } // end if 

  } // end do
while ($i<=$num_rows);
```

Comment: you need to fetch the row first, using mysql_fetch_* functions

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 2):

This is something a basic PHP/MySQL tutorial will teach you. `mysql_query()` results a resource identifier. You still need to go and get your results using `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT Description FROM csv");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

  if (strpos($row['description'],$searchterm) !== false) {
```

I also recommend following the advice in the comments above. You're writing code that is is obsolete as you type.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($description) >=1){
 $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($description);
  $words = $result['Description'];
 if (strpos($word ,$searchterm) !== false) {
          echo $word. "<br><br>";
      } 
}
```

Count if rows are returned first and then fetch. And important, use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead of `mysql`. It's deprecated.